# error 401 in the command when try to install fontawesome in next js

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, icons

I get this error when I tried to install `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` in my **nextjs** project, I tried some things and didn´t work, this is the error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-23T23_16_48_750Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Next.js or `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`, looks like an npm issue. Have you tried running `npm login` as suggested in the error message?

Comment: yes, I tried but it doesn't work